# How To Add Shimmer for Android Library in My Project Android Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, android-library

i am new in Android. please help me How To Add Shimmer for Android Library in My Project Android Eclipse. here is link of  [Shimmer for Android](https://github.com/RomainPiel/Shimmer-android)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
1) Download library from here - https://github.com/RomainPiel/Shimmer-android/releases
2) In eclipse
    - Right click package explorer -> New -> Other -> Android project from existing code
    - Browse to location of shimmer library download
    - Under project to import, choose project 'library' .( Only library is required. No need sample)
    - Rename it to something like 'shimmer' under new project name section for library otherwise it will be name 'main'
    - Mark copy project to workspace to maintain separate copy of library
    - Finish

    Now in package explorer
    - Goto 'java' folder of shimmer
    - Right click -> Build path -> use as source folder
    - Right click -> properties -> Android -> Mark 'is library'
    - Clean

3) Now add library to any project
    - Right click target project -> properties 
    - Goto Android 
    - Click Add under library panel
    - choose shimmer -> Apply

4) Clean project
```

Comment: Thanks i follow this steps and Shimmer for Android. but `shimmer = new Shimmer();
        shimmer.start(myShimmerTextView);` **ERROR** shimmer cannot be resolved to a variable

Comment: @Virat21 i had updated answer. Did you follow steps in adding java as source folder?

Comment: Right click -> Build path -> use as source folder when i do this shimmer.java Got an Error see image [link](http://s4.postimg.org/7sno4dk8d/image.png)

Answer (score 0):

Now you can add this gradle in android studio.

```
dependencies {
               compile 'com.facebook.shimmer:shimmer:0.1.0@aar'
             }
```